# Stored procedure with Try Catch Block is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to write a stored procedure to copy one table's data into another. If any corrupt records (eg: `null` records) appear during copying, those records need to bypassed and the copying should continue with next record.

I have columns in destination table to identity which offices are copied and which are not copied. I have tried below stored procedure with `try catch block`:

```
CREATE TABLE OFFICE_new 
(
    id int identity, 
    officeid int null, 
    ok int,
    notok int
)

CREATE TABLE OFFICE_old 
( 
    id int identity, 
    officeid int null
)

insert into OFFICE_old (officeid)
values (1000),(2000),(3000),(4000),(null),(6000)
go

alter procedure exception_check
as
begin
   begin try
   begin tran 
        insert into OFFICE_new (officeid)
            select officeid
            from OFFICE_old

        if @@error = 0
        begin
            update OFFICE_new 
            set ok = 1

            commit tran 
        end
    end try
    begin  catch
        insert into OFFICE_new (officeid,notok)
            select officeid, 1
            from OFFICE_old
        commit tran
    end catch
end
```

This stored procedure should insert copied offices with `'ok' = 1` and failed offices with `'notok' = 1`. but it isn't working.

Thanks for help.

Comment: It didn't copied any records

Comment: You really shouldn't use TRY/CATCH as a flow control for you code. You should check to see if a record exists in your `OFFICE_new` table and either update or insert depending on the outcome.

Comment: not clear what are you trying to achieve

Comment: giorgi Nakeuri.  I have to copy million number of records (officeid's) from one table to another. I need the transaction need to be completed even if some inserts are failed. I also need to know which are the failed records.

Comment: You would probably be better off creating a cursor that you can iterate over, start a transaction, start a try, attempt to insert 1 record at a time as `ok`, if it fails, catch then insert as `notok`, commit transaction, loop. That is, if you really need the try/catch, I would think this would all be avoided by using proper checks before attempting to insert. Exceptions should be a last resort, you know - something that is "exceptional".

Comment: so you think iterating each record with try/catch block with work?

Comment: That is just one possible idea, but you are only showing, i imagine, a small portion of what you are wanting to do. You should have some known criteria that determines if a record is "corrupt", you should perform those checks instead of just attempting to insert it blindly. If it passes the check logic, insert the full record, if it doesn't pass, insert the record id and a value indicating it was corrupted.

Comment: SQL is a set based language.  Performance can be problem when trying to work at the record level (esp at scale).  Have you looked into SSIS?  This has some great record level tools.  You can pipe "good" and "bad" records to separate destinations.

Comment: unfortunately i dont have constraints like that. its a very big transaction with more than 1 crore records. I will do this in iterative approach to track the non-inserted records. But I wonder, why it isn't possible in set-based approach.

Comment: destination-data. I am aware about ssis. But I cant go for that because it is not just blindly copying. For each records I have to make specific calculations. So execute-sql task with stored procedure is a only way in ssis i think

Comment: It would be possible to do this as one or two queries, you would just need to have all of your validation logic available: `insert into table1 (id, name, address, isvalid) select id, name, address, case when name is not null and address is not null then 1 else 0 end from table2;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple things wrong with your query.

First your @@error check seems incorrect. Are you sure you're not after `@@error = 0`?

Also your commit statement is located inside the IF so if you do not reach the IF - you'll never commit.

```
 if @@error <>0
        begin
        update OFFICE_new set ok = 1
        commit tran /*<---- will not commit if you do not reach */
        end
```

Also - in your catch you still try to insert that which went wrong in your transaction, so you'll get another error.
You're trying to insert NULL into officeid.

```
 insert into OFFICE_new (officeid,notok)
        select officeid, 1
        from OFFICE_old /* one of the values are NULL */
```

So that'll fail as well and therefore not set 'notok'

Comment: yes @@error = 0 is a correct one.  I have removed not null constraint for officeid. i just need to get track of the records which are failed

Answer (score 1):

remove @@error statement and alter procedure as:

```
alter procedure exception_check
as
begin
begin try
begin tran 
        insert into OFFICE_new (officeid,notok,ok)
        select officeid,0 as notok,1 as ok
        from OFFICE_old
        commit tran 
    end try
    begin  catch
          insert into OFFICE_new (officeid,notok,ok)
        select officeid,1 as notok,0 as ok
        from OFFICE_old
    commit tran
    end catch
end
```